# What should be a replacement for StoreType.HASH_MAP in spring-boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to migrate application from spring-boot 1.5.9.RELEASE to 2.0.0.CR1.

In the spring-boot 2 `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.StoreType.HASH_MAP` was removed. In my application it was used in application.yml

```
spring:
  session:
    store-type: hash_map
```

What should I do to preserve previous behavior with new version of spring-boot and why this store-type was removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following:

```
@EnableSpringHttpSession
@Configuration
public class SpringHttpSessionConfig {
  @Bean
  public MapSessionRepository sessionRepository() {
    return new MapSessionRepository(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
  }
}
```

see equivalent [question](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1228#issuecomment-432320976) on SpringSession git repository

Answer (score 1):

Below config worked for me. This configuration was used for testing and lower environment. for production we used **redis** instead of **none or hash_map**.

Add below code in application-local.yml file.

```
spring:
  session:
    store-type: none

server:
  servlet:
    max-http-header-size: 20000
    session:
      cookie:
        max-age: 300 # absolute session timeout in seconds
      timeout: 300
```

Create config class.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.session.MapSessionRepository;
import org.springframework.session.SessionRepository;
import org.springframework.session.config.annotation.web.http.EnableSpringHttpSession;
import org.springframework.session.web.http.HeaderHttpSessionStrategy;
import org.springframework.session.web.http.HttpSessionStrategy;

@EnableSpringHttpSession
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.session", value = "store-type", havingValue = "none")
public class HttpSessionConfig {

  @Value("${server.servlet.session.timeout:300}")
  private Integer maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds;


  @Bean
  public SessionRepository sessionRepository() {
    SessionRepository sessionRepository = new MapSessionRepository(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    ((MapSessionRepository) sessionRepository)
        .setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds);
    return sessionRepository;
  }
}
```